# Bypassing windows xp passwords without CD or USB

Tags: windows-xp, boot, dell-latitude, bypass

I got 2 PC's here, that my mother asked to fix, but I can't log in. Admin accounts have a password set. I can't boot from USB, they're to old and don't support it. The DVD drive doesn't seem to be working either, though I can't tell if it's broken or just not allowing me to boot.

Is there any way to get in windows XP SP2, without a password, USB or DVD?

The computer is a Dell latitude C840.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove the hard disks and attach them to a computer that will boot from USB or DVD. Then use standard techniques. Finally replace disks in original computer.

Comment: Ah yes, I'll see how that works with laptops

Comment: Can't get the latest screw unscrewed, almost seems like it's sealed with glue

Comment: Might be easier to install a working cd/dvd rom.

Answer (score 1):

If it is XP Home edition, boot into safe mode, this is the hidden administrator account, hopefully no one ever password protected it, it is not by default. Once in safe mode you can use control panel to clear passwords.

If it asks for a password, leave it blank and hit enter, if this does not work you will have to try the suggestion by RedGrittyBrick.

Comment: "Admin accounts have a password set.", so that won't work

Comment: @SimonVerbeke Is the Administrator (the built in) account password protected?

Comment: @Luke Yes, that one as well